# Uniformly delegated properties in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

When you have a backing object that you would like to wrap and delegate all properties with the same delegate logic, is there some way to generically describe a class implementation with all the properties delegated the same way? Take the example below:

```
class Subject<T, U>(
    private val prop : KMutableProperty0<U>
) {
    operator fun getValue(caller: T, prop: KProperty<*>) : U = this.prop.get()
    operator fun setValue(caller: T, prop: KProperty<*>, value : U) {
        // dostuff
        this.prop.set(value)
    }
}

interface Test {
    val prop1 : String
    val prop2 : String
}

@Serializable
class TestImpl(
    override var prop1: String,
    override var prop2: String
) : Test


// I don't want to have to write this boilerplate every time I need to delegate logic from a serializeable data object
class Wrapper( val test : TestImpl) : Test {
    override var prop1 by Subject(testImpl::prop1)
    override var prop2 by Subject(testImpl::prop2)
}
```

Is there any language feature that would let me write something like this:

```
class GenericWrapper<T , U : T>(val impl : U) : T /* can't do this obviously */{
    // for each property on T, overwrite the property and delegate accordingly
}
```

The only thing I can think of at this point is writing my own compiler plugin, but is this the only option?

Comment: hey. Sorry, the purpose of `Wrapper` it's not really clear for me. Maybe class delegation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html will suit you ?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, have you considered using the type `Test`? The whole point of interfaces is to hide the implementation details, which is what it sounds like you're trying to do. Why do we need a concrete type that exists as a wrapper?

Comment: I think I understand what OP means, because... well, I'm just writing a Kotlin/Java utility to help with such scenarios :-D Imagine that we have interface `Test` with a lot of fields and we would like to log all prop reads in uniform way. We can write a wrapper that logs reads and delegates to the real object. The problem is, we need to implement all these props in our wrapper. We can write a property delegate to make our wrapper at least a little more concise, but the best would be if we could say that our wrapper should generate delegations to another object, but through delegate property.

Comment: @broot, precisely :). The specific example in my case is to apply something like observables to all properties on the data class for binding to dom like views, but logging is another example use case. The problem boils down to wanting to apply the exact same delegation logic to each property in the object without the boilerplate of writing a new delegation wrapper for each instance.

Comment: Is this a case for Java's [dynamic proxy classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html)?